# Using VBA paste excel chart in powerpoint and also keep source formatting

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to paste an excel chart in a powerpoint slide, however, losing the source formatting in the process. Request you to please help me with the code.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
Sub EuropeMoneyBall()

Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim MainWB As Workbook
Dim MBSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim MBSheet2 As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'*****************Open Excel file where charts are saved*********************

Workbooks.Open Filename:="J:\Research\Internal\Moneyball.xlsx"
Set MainWB = Workbooks("Moneyball.xlsx")
Set MBSheet1 = MainWB.Sheets("1Y Charts")
Set MBSheet2 = MainWB.Sheets("3Y Charts")

'*****************Open Powerpoint where charts are to be saved********************

If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(16)

MBSheet1.Activate
MBSheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy

With mySlide
    With .Shapes.Paste
        .Top = Application.CentimetersToPoints(4.11)
        .Left = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.73)
        .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(9.47)
        .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(11.54)
    End With
End With

myPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"

MBSheet2.Activate
MBSheet2.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy

With mySlide
    With .Shapes.Paste
        .Top = Application.CentimetersToPoints(4.11)
        .Left = Application.CentimetersToPoints(12.87)
        .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(9.47)
        .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(11.54)
    End With
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Rohan